# configuring atom IDE with atom runner

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to find a decent ide for python3, and atom sounded a good choice, but the atom runner is not very interactive. For example this simple code produces an error, I'm pasting a screenshot, to show the problem as it is:

[image]

Can I configure atom to execute code interactively. The way I noticed the problem was that atom runner first executes all of the code and then ONLY displays the output. Is there a fix or any packages for this?

If not, please suggest a descent and simple to use IDE for python. If there was something like the online [repl.it](http://repl.it) but for offline use, it would really fit my taste.

Answer (score 1):

For atom there is a package called The Terminal Plus Package: https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus, this will open a virtual terminal that will have a the capabilities of a normal terminal. Hope I helped!

-Zeus

Comment: thanks for the answer, and it was what I was seeking for, however, after I installed it. It doesn't appear below the screen. If you have installed it please tell me what do we need to do to trigger the pseudoterminal. Because, I couldn't really figure anything out from the given documentation.

Comment: The docs say that using "control-`" should open a new window, but if not I do not know.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but it didn't work. thanks for the answer though.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I'm on linux, ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but maybe you could search on Stack Overflow.